# slow workstation computer with expensive components

Tags: cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer, dual-gpu

I recently spent a fortune to buy a powerful workstation, expecting it to be much faster than my Thinkpad P53 laptop and my Dell Precision Tower Desktop, since the server is about 4 times as costly as the P53 or the Dell desktop computer.

The component list for my server computer

[image]

However, it turns out the server is much slower than my P53 or the Dell desktop computer.
Its startup typically takes more than 2 minutes.
I try to use software like cloudcompare, office word in it.
It is so slow that each mouse click takes a few seconds.
For comparison, my P53 laptop spends less than 0.5 second for each such operation.

Why is this?

Comment: Which OS? And are the graphics drivers (Nvidia) correctly installed? If Linux you must have the drivers from the **535** branch at the time of this writing.

Comment: The computer has dual boot with windows 10 and ubuntu 22. The windows seems slower than ubuntu 22. I have run point cloud segmentation tasks based on the deep neural networks in ubuntu, where we installed the nvidia driver 535(https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/) for cuda 12.

Answer (score 1):

Xeons may be more expensive than other processors but that doesn't mean that they are better for every job. Their high core count generally means that they do not have as high a single core clock boost speed,

[That Xeon 8336 has a maximum boost of 3.6GHz](https://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/SR/SRKJ5.html) while the [i7-9750H available in some Lenovo P53 laptops can boost up to 4.5GHz](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191045/intel-core-i7-9750h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-50-ghz.html). For tasks that require only a few cores the i7 could absolutely trounce the Xeon. The Xeon will win on high core count tasks.

Servers are typically a lot slower to start up than normal PCs. Most servers I've seen have a very extensive management interface that checks all the hardware and other interfaces before booting an operating system it could be that is slowing down your boot.

If your computer is slow on graphically demanding tasks then you may need to check that drivers are properly installed and working.

Answer (score 0):

Run apps which use multi core architecture or use intensively GPU like 3D rendering, image edit and export, video editing, AI. Also run several virtual machines and you will see how powerful is the workstation. You can get also benefits when you load huge file(s) (to use these 32GB or RAM).

Then you will see the benefits of your workstation.